# Why did the insignia of the Republic change from eight to six spikes from Star Wars Episode 2 to Episode 3?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, attack-of-the-clones

In Star Wars Episode II, the roundels on the ships of the Galactic Republic have eight spikes. In Star Wars Episode 3, they have only six spikes. Why did the logo change? We can guess that cannot be due to the forming of the Empire because we can see six-spiked symbols early in the movie, while the Empire is only founded at the end.

Why did the insignia of the Republic change from eight to six spikes from Episode 2 to Episode 3?

Comment: A sign to the audience that the Republic from the start of the clone wars is not the same peaceful government as seen in Episode 3 (more militaristic and like a dictatorship, etc.)

Comment: when do you notice the change in the logo in E3? Is it prior to or after this speech? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS57I6swXcc

Comment: Two of the spikes were clearly loyal to the Confederacy of Independent Systems.

Comment: Hmm. The [ROTS Cross-Section](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_Incredible_Cross-Sections) book calls it a "reduced form" of the emblem, but doesn't explain why it's used.

Comment: It's noticeable that Anakin had it on his fighter *before* the Empire was declared. I suspect it's a case of the tail wagging the dog. They used the wrong logo, then justified it later.

Comment: @Valorum - so maybe a more streamlined military version vs formal?

Comment: @NKCampbell - Possibly. It's not in any way clear. The "Star Wars Propaganda" book doesn't mention the reason for the change either.

Comment: Some [official merchandise](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/TXcAAMXQjq5Q~HMx/s-l1600.jpg) has shown it as having six spikes as of Attack of the Clones, but it's more likely just a mistake or a reused sticker.

Comment: I think a picture would be nice